# FindGameObjectsWithTag finds to much objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a some `GameObjects` DustStorm with a `ParticleSystem` on it.

I want to store all the ParticleSystems in an `Array`, so i use the code below:

```
GameObject[] dustStormGameObjects;
ParticleSystem[] dustStorms;

dustStormGameObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("FxDustStorm");
Debug.Log(dustStormGameObjects.Length.ToString());
dustStorms = new ParticleSystem[dustStormGameObjects.Length];
for (var i = 0; i < dustStormGameObjects.Length; i++)
{
    Debug.Log(dustStormGameObjects[i].name.ToString());
    dustStorms[i] = dustStormGameObjects[i].GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
    Debug.Log(dustStormGameObjects[i].name.ToString());
}
```

I have some Debug.Logs (that you can see in the code) to get informations about the length of the `Array` and the names of the `GameObjects` within the `Array`.

My Problem is: When i have for example 5 DustStorms in the Scene, the first Debug.Log returns 6.

The second Debug.Log (that should get the names) shows me always one times `null`. The rest are "DustStorm", so they are correct.

The only objects i have in the scene that have the tag "FxDustStorm" are the DustStorms.

Edit: here is a screenshot from the console:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a `DustStorm` object in your scene before running it up? I bet it is that. By this I mean when you edit your scene in Unity is there an object in the list?

Comment: you have a game object with that tag which does not have a particle system attached to it. or the particle system isn't attached yet for some reason.

Comment: remove the tag, use another tag and try again if you couldn't find that object

Comment: @Bijington no, there is none.

Comment: @Bijan i took another tag today and it works fine now. thanks.